# Set up size of button (javafx) using css

Tags: java, css, button, javafx, size

I create a button and I want to set up its width and height through css. I tried this but it didn't work.
Other properties( such as font-size and text fill) are fine and work correctly. But the width of Button seems to be fixed and doesn't change.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        VBox root = new VBox();
        Button button = new Button("Button");
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Style.css").toExternalForm());
        button.setId("button");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And in "Style.css":

```
#button{
    -fx-width: 300;
    -fx-font-size:20;
    -fx-text-fill: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Use one or more of `-fx-min-width`, `-fx-pref-width`, or `-fx-max-width`.

Comment: Check out the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) to see what properties are available.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. -fx-pref-width works well.

Comment: @James_D please help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62200942/about-pausetransition-in-javafx