# About PauseTransition in javafx

Tags: java, button, javafx, eventhandler, pause

I created a VBox (root) and added some Button in it. When I click the button with text "Click" (button_to_click), ten other button (an button array with ten elements) will change background color into 'red'. I want per button change its backgr color per second. I used PauseTransition to do this but it didn't work. Here are my code

```
package sample;

import javafx.animation.PauseTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        VBox root = new VBox();

        Button button_to_click = new Button("Click");

        Button[] buttons = new Button[10];

        root.getChildren().add(button_to_click);

        for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
            buttons[i] = new Button(""+i);
            root.getChildren().add(buttons[i]);
        }

        button_to_click.setOnAction(e->{
            for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
                buttons[i].setStyle("-fx-background-color:red");
                PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
                pause.play();
            }
        });


        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

All button change its background color at the same time, that isn't what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You are treating PauseTransition like it’s a Thread.sleep call.  But PauseTransition does not work like that.

And even if it were the same, a sleep call would not do what you want.  JavaFX, like most user interface toolkits, is single threaded, so a sleep call would hang the application.

The pause transition occurs in a background thread.  What you want is to change a button’s color when the pause [finishes](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#onFinishedProperty):

```
button_to_click.setOnAction(e -> {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        Button button = buttons[i];

        PauseTransition pause = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(i));
        pause.setOnFinished(
            f -> button.setStyle("-fx-background-color:red"));
        pause.play();
    }
});
```

Notice that I have changed the PauseTransition’s duration from `seconds(1)` to `seconds(i)`.  This isn’t the most efficient approach, but it requires the fewest changes to your existing code.  It will cause each button’s `setStyle` method to be invoked after `i` seconds have passed.